# Not getting access token with elance gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on Elance api integration using elance gem then get_access_token method is not working for getting access token.

http://rubydoc.info/gems/elance/1.0.2/frames

Getting undefined method "ap" in below line no. 38 and I think it will not use in gem

https://github.com/NetVersaLLC/elance_gem/blob/master/lib/elance/authentication.rb

I am stuck here please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you find any answer so far... I am also trying to access the elance api, but am not able to get the access tokens after getting the authorization code from elance.

Answer (score 0):

I did research and got solution. that "omniauth-elance" gem is not worked for getting access token so, you need to checkout Elance API documentation. and use "httparty" gem for getting json response.

I have write below code in which i used AccessToken Model for save record once into database. and it is associated with User model. and its working for me.

```
  response = HTTParty.post("https://api.elance.com/api2/oauth/token", :body => { :code => params[:code], :grant_type => 'authorization_code', :client_id => 'add your client id here', :client_secret => 'add your client secret here'})
  json_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
  access_token = json_response['data']['access_token']
  @access_token = AccessToken.new(:access_token  => json_response['data']['access_token'],
                                  :expired_at    => Time.now + json_response['data']['expires_in'].to_i,
                                  :status        => 'Active',
                                  :source        => 'Elance',
                                  :user_id       => current_user.id,
                                  :refresh_token => json_response['data']['refresh_token']
                                    )
  @access_token.save!
  CustomMailer.send_code_mail(params[:code], access_token).deliver

  flash[:notice] = "Successfully Connected to Elance"
  redirect_to rails_admin_path
```